# Prove if $A$ is a symmetric matrix with real entries, then the eigenvalues of $A$ are real.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Given a matrix 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ b& c \end{bmatrix} $$

then let $\lambda = p+qi$ be a complex eigenvalue of $A$.

I used the characteristic equation to get a factorizacion of
$i(2pq - aq - qc)$ because I thought I would get zero. But it didn´t work.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a factorization of ...."?

Comment: When you use the characteristic equation( det(A- lamba)= 0) you get a huge equation with some numbers with "i". So I made the factorizacion of that equation thinking that would be zero. Thats only a idea i had, i'm not sure thats the way to solve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denote the complex inner product. Suppose $v$ is a nonzero eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $$\lambda \langle v, v \rangle = \langle Av, v \rangle = \langle v, A^{T} v \rangle = \langle v, Av \rangle = \overline{\lambda} \langle v, v \rangle$$ Hence $\lambda = \overline{\lambda} \implies \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

*Alternative proof:* Compute the characteristic polynomial $$\det(x\cdot \text{Id} - A) = (x-a)(x-c)-b^2 = x^2 - (a+c)x + ac-b^2$$ This quadratic has discriminant $$(a+c)^2 - 4(ac-b^2) = (a-c)^2 + 4b^2 \ge 0$$ Therefore, its roots (i.e., the eigenvalues of $A$) are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you know another way to proove it? I'm not supposed to know that theory for my exam and their are asking me that question in an exercise. I'm trying to understand the Hermitian Inner Product but my exam is tomorrow.

Comment: Added an alternative proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the **real symmetric** matrix, $x$ the eigen vector and $\lambda$ the eigen value. Then 
$$Ax=\lambda x \implies (Ax)^*=Ax^*=(\lambda x)^*=\lambda^*x^* $$
Also
$$(Ax).x^*=(\lambda x).x^*=\lambda||x||^2 $$
Similarly $$(Ax^*).x=(\lambda^* x^*).x=\lambda^*||x||^2 $$
LHS are equal since: $$(Ax).x^*=(A^Tx^*).x=(Ax^*).x$$
Now equate RHS to give:
$$\lambda^*||x||^2=\lambda||x||^2\implies \lambda=\lambda^*$$